# Parsing CSV File enclosed with quotes in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I've seen lots of samples in parsing CSV File. but this one is kind of annoying file...

so how do you parse this kind of CSV

"1",1/2/2010,"The sample ("adasdad") asdada","I was pooping in the door "Stinky", so I'll be damn","AK"

Comment: Is `The sample ("adasdad") asdada` a single value or you expect it to be split to `The sample (`, `adasdad` and `) asdada` as you haven't escaped the double quotes.

Comment: According to the CSV RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt double quotes have to be escaped by another double quote. Otherwise you have no chance to tell which double quote encloses your string. So the creator of the CSV should be in the responsibility to escape the double quotes correctly

Comment: I agree with comments stating about malformed CSV. However, there are still too many real world situation where you have to cope with this anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best answer in most cases is probably @Jim Mischel's. `TextFieldParser` seems to be exactly what you want for most conventional cases -- though it strangely [lives in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace!](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/07/whats-a-nice-class-like-textfieldparser-doing-in-a-namespace.aspx)  **But this case isn't conventional.**

The last time I ran into a variation on this issue where I needed something unconventional, I embarrassingly gave up on regexp'ing and bullheaded a char by char check.  Sometimes, that's not-wrong enough to do.  Splitting a string isn't as difficult a problem if you byte push.

So I rewrote for this case as a string extension.  I think this is close.

Do note that, `"I was pooping in the door "Stinky", so I'll be damn",` is an especially nasty case. Without the `*** STINKY CONDITION ***` code, below, you'd get `I was pooping in the door "Stinky` as one value and `so I'll be damn"` as the other.

The only way to do better than that *for any anonymous weird splitter/escape case* would be to have some sort of algorithm to determine the "usual" number of columns in each row, and then check for, in this case, fixed length fields like your `AK` state entry or some other possible landmark as a sort of normalizing backstop for nonconformist columns.  But that's serious crazy logic that likely isn't called for, as much fun as it'd be to code.  As @Vash points out, you're better off following *some* standard and coding a little more OFfensively.

But the problem here is probably easier than that.  **The only lexically meaningful case is the one in your example -- `",` -- double quote, comma, and then a space.** So that's what the `*** STINKY CONDITION ***` code checks.  Even so, this code is getting nastier than I'd like, which means you have ever stranger edge cases, like `"This is also stinky," a f a b","Now what?"`  Heck, even `"A,"B","C"` doesn't work in this code right now, iirc, since I treat the begin and end chars as having been escape pre- and post-fixed.  So we're largely back to @Vash's comment!

Apologies for all the brackets for one-line `if` statements, but I'm stuck in a StyleCop world right now.  I'm not necessarily suggesting you use this -- that `strictEscapeToSplitEvaluation` plus the STINKY CONDITION makes this a little complex.  But it's worth keeping in mind that a normal csv parser that's intelligent about quotes is significantly more straightforward to the point of being tedious, but otherwise trivial.

```
namespace YourFavoriteNamespace 
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Queue<string> SplitSeeingQuotes(this string valToSplit, char splittingChar = ',', char escapeChar = '"', 
            bool strictEscapeToSplitEvaluation = true, bool captureEndingNull = false)
        {
            Queue<string> qReturn = new Queue<string>();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            bool bInEscapeVal = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < valToSplit.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!bInEscapeVal)
                {
                    // Escape values must come immediately after a split.
                    // abc,"b,ca",cab has an escaped comma.
                    // abc,b"ca,c"ab does not.
                    if (escapeChar == valToSplit[i] && (!strictEscapeToSplitEvaluation || (i == 0 || (i != 0 && splittingChar == valToSplit[i - 1]))))
                    {
                        bInEscapeVal = true;    // not capturing escapeChar as part of value; easy enough to change if need be.
                    }
                    else if (splittingChar == valToSplit[i])
                    {
                        qReturn.Enqueue(stringBuilder.ToString());
                        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(valToSplit[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Can't use switch b/c we're comparing to a variable, I believe.
                    if (escapeChar == valToSplit[i])
                    {
                        // Repeated escape always reduces to one escape char in this logic.
                        // So if you wanted "I'm ""double quote"" crazy!" to come out with 
                        // the double double quotes, you're toast.
                        if (i + 1 < valToSplit.Length && escapeChar == valToSplit[i + 1])
                        {
                            i++;
                            stringBuilder.Append(escapeChar);
                        }
                        else if (!strictEscapeToSplitEvaluation)
                        {
                            bInEscapeVal = false;
                        }
                        // *** STINKY CONDITION ***  
                        // Kinda defense, since only `", ` really makes sense.
                        else if ('"' == escapeChar && i + 2 < valToSplit.Length &&
                            valToSplit[i + 1] == ',' && valToSplit[i + 2] == ' ')
                        {
                            i = i+2;
                            stringBuilder.Append("\", ");
                        }
                        // *** EO STINKY CONDITION ***  
                        else if (i+1 == valToSplit.Length || (i + 1 < valToSplit.Length && valToSplit[i + 1] == splittingChar))
                        {
                            bInEscapeVal = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append(escapeChar);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(valToSplit[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // NOTE: The `captureEndingNull` flag is not tested.
            // Catch null final entry?  "abc,cab,bca," could be four entries, with the last an empty string.
            if ((captureEndingNull && splittingChar == valToSplit[valToSplit.Length-1]) || (stringBuilder.Length > 0))
            {
                qReturn.Enqueue(stringBuilder.ToString());
            }

            return qReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Probably worth mentioning that the ["answer" you gave yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905742/1028230) doesn't have the "Stinky" problem in its sample string.  ;^)

[Understanding that we're three years after you asked,] I will say that your example isn't as insane as folks here make out.  I can see wanting to treat escape characters (in this case, `"`) as escape characters *only when they're the first value after the splitting character or, after finding an opening escape, stopping only if you find the escape character before a splitter*; in this case, the splitter is obviously `,`.

If the row of your csv is `abc,bc"a,ca"b`, I would expect that to mean we've got three values: `abc`, `bc"a`, and `ca"b`.

Same deal in your `"The sample ("adasdad") asdada"` column -- quotes that don't begin and end a cell value aren't escape characters and don't necessarily need doubling to maintain meaning.  So I added a `strictEscapeToSplitEvaluation` flag here.

Enjoy.  ;^)

Comment: Thanks for the most comprehensive answer ever. thanks for the effort and time sir! answers like this makes stackoverflow the best place to get answers to your programming predicaments.

Comment: If any1 will try to use it, I found an issue. I'm splitting by ';'. When I change `captureEndingNull` to `true`, and got line like `a;b;c;;;;;aaa` The `aaa` value isn't captured, and method throw an error, that index is out of range :) If the last value is empty - the same situation.

Comment: Solution: You cant access `valToSplit[valToSplit.Length]`. The last element is `valToSplit[valToSplit.Length - 1]`.

Comment: @titol You're right; thanks. Guessing I haven't tested `captureEndingNull` set to true, or at least didn't after making some changes. As [Shackles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/170333/greg-shackles) would say, I need to write some tests. If you beat me to it, I won't be upset. ;^) I'll make the change now, but won't guarantee it works until I've tested...

Comment: @ruffin I did some tests, and in the captureEndingNull StringBuilder.Length should be >= 0 :)

Comment: @ruffin This was like a game. I came across this on accident and had to get it working in my csv parser for fun too. https://github.com/rhyous/EasyCsv.

Comment: @Rhyous [Test case LOL](https://github.com/rhyous/EasyCsv/commit/bf1ac8de235cfbc1ed6f2eede6e1754757918070#diff-a4b34b9d2018dc8d398647494ee537ddR359)! Yeah, it was a really fun question, especially once I figured out the "*The only lexically meaningful case is the one in your example -- `", ` -- double quote, comma, and then a space.*" stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I very strongly recommend using [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). Hand-coded parsers that use `String.Split` or regular expressions almost invariably mishandle things like quoted fields that have embedded quotes or embedded separators.

I would be surprised, though, if it handled your particular example. As others have said, that line is, at best, ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Split based on

> ",

I would use MyString.IndexOf("\","

And then substring the parts. Other then that im sure someone written a csv parser out there that can handle this :)

Comment: Either that, or the OP's example is a badly-formed CSV file intended to test CSV parsers.

Comment: I've written a CSV parser that works great, but it couldn't possibly know where to split the line. It's hard for me to tell myself because it's malformed. Finding `",` will not find the end of the second field. And if there's lots of lines, then it becomes impossible to make simple rules about how to do this. That's why the CSV format has certain requirements, which are not met here.

Comment: splitting on ", will fail on "the "good", the "bad", and the "ugly"".

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to parse this malformed CSV. I looked for a pattern and found it.... I first replace (",") with a character... like "¤" and then split it...

from this:

```
"Annoying","CSV File","poop@mypants.com",1999,01-20-2001,"oh,boy",01-20-2001,"yeah baby","yeah!"
```

to this:

```
"Annoying¤CSV File¤poop@mypants.com",1999,01-20-2001,"oh,boy",01-20-2001,"yeah baby¤yeah!"
```

then split it:

```
ArrayA[0]: "Annoying //this value will be trimmed by replace("\"","") same as the array[4]
ArrayA[1]: CSV File
ArrayA[2]: poop@mypants.com",1999,01-20-2001,"oh,boy",01-20-2001,"yeah baby
ArrayA[3]: yeah!"
```

after splitting it, I will replace strings from ArrayA[2] ", and ," with ¤ and then split it again

from this

```
ArrayA[2]: poop@mypants.com",1999,01-20-2001,"oh,boy",01-20-2001,"yeah baby
```

to this

```
ArrayA[2]: poop@mypants.com¤1999,01-20-2001¤oh,boy¤01-20-2001¤yeah baby
```

then split it again and would turn to this

```
ArrayB[0]: poop@mypants.com
ArrayB[1]: 1999,01-20-2001
ArrayB[2]: oh,boy
ArrayB[3]: 01-20-2001
ArrayB[4]: yeah baby
```

and lastly... I'll split the Year only and the date from ArrayB[1] with , to ArrayC

It's tedious but there's no other way to do it...

Comment: after looking and carefully studying 3++,+++ rows CSV file in open office Calc... I saw a pattern... and lead me to this conclusion. hope i can find a shorter algo for this...

Answer (score 1):

There is one another open source library, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/), handle quoted string fine. Here is sample code.

```
string csv = @"""1"",1/2/2010,""The sample(""adasdad"") asdada"",""I was pooping in the door ""Stinky"", so I'll be damn"",""AK""";

using (var r = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv)
    .QuoteAllFields()
    )
{
    foreach (var rec in r)
        Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Count: 5]
Key: Column1 [Type: Int64]
Value: 1
Key: Column2 [Type: DateTime]
Value: 1/2/2010 12:00:00 AM
Key: Column3 [Type: String]
Value: The sample(adasdad) asdada
Key: Column4 [Type: String]
Value: I was pooping in the door Stinky, so I'll be damn
Key: Column5 [Type: String]
Value: AK
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by `","`. It is recomended that the csv file could each cell value should be enclosed in quotes like "1","2","3".....

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could if each line is different. This line is a malformed for CSV. Quotes contained within a value must be doubled as shown below. I can't even tell for sure where the values should be terminated.

```
"1",1/2/2010,"The sample (""adasdad"") asdada","I was pooping in the door ""Stinky"", so I'll be damn","AK"
```

[Here's my code to parse a CSV file](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c) but I don't see how any code would know how to handle your line because it's malformed.

Comment: Because his above example has , inside the quotes. So you have to look for the ",

Comment: Yeah! that's what i'm talking about... i mean why would they do that... the format is soooo annoying... I Can't do anything regarding the format of the CSV so I need to do something radical to parse this damn CSV file... anyway thanks for the answer...

Comment: @EKS: Looking for `",` would not find the end of the second field (the date). The line is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) a try. It will handle quoted string fine, so you just will have to remove leading and trailing quotes.

It will fail if your strings contains a coma. To avoid this, the quotes needs to be doubled as said in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

As no (decent) .csv parser can parse non-csv-data correctly, the task isn't to parse the data, but to fix the file(s) (and then to parse the correct data).

To fix the data you need a list of bad rows (to be sent to the person responsible for the garbage for manual editing). To get such a list, you can

1. use Access with a correct import specification to import the file. You'll get a list of import failures.
2. write a script/program that opens the file via the OLEDB text driver.

Sample file:

```
"Id","Remark","DateDue"
1,"This is good",20110413
2,"This is ""good""",20110414
3,"This is ""good"","bad",and "ugly",,20110415
4,"This is ""good""" again,20110415
```

Sample SQL/Result:

```
 SELECT * FROM [badcsv01.csv]
 Id Remark               DateDue   
  1 This is good         4/13/2011 
  2 This is "good"       4/14/2011 
  3 This is "good",        NULL    
  4 This is "good" again 4/15/2011 

SELECT * FROM [badcsv01.csv] WHERE DateDue Is Null
 Id Remark          DateDue 
  3 This is "good",  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will do it for the columns names:

```
            DataTable pbResults = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            oda.Fill(pbResults);

            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = pbResults.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);

            sb1.Append(string.Join("\"" + "," + "\"", columnNames));                
            sb2.Append("\"");
            sb2.Append(sb1);
            sb2.AppendLine("\"");
```

Second you will do it for each row:

```
            foreach (DataRow row in pbResults.Rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                sb2.Append("\"");
                sb2.Append(string.Join("\"" + "," + "\"", fields));
                sb2.AppendLine("\"");
            }
```