# How do I get the last four characters from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have a string:

```
"34234234d124"
```

I want to get the last four characters of this string which is `"d124"`. I can use `SubString`, but it needs a couple of lines of code, including naming a variable.

Is it possible to get this result in one expression with C#?

Comment: What do you want when there are fewer than 4 characters?

Comment: `4 > mystring.length ? mystring : mystring.Substring(mystring.length -4);`

Comment: In Python the solution is simple: `"hello world"[-4:]`. I hope a future version of C# will make it as easy.

Comment: @ColonelPanic, now you can with C# 8.0: `"hello world"[^4..]` :-)

Comment: @FrodeEvensen What is the name of the function you're demonstrating there so I can read more about it?

Comment: @neberu, Ranges: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Comment: This link focuses on usage of the implemented feature, vs the proposal of the other link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes

Answer (score 538):

```
mystring.Substring(Math.Max(0, mystring.Length - 4)); //how many lines is this?
```

If you're positive the length of your string is at least 4, then it's even shorter:

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4);
```

Comment: Also, it'll fail if `mystring` is less than 4 chars long.

Comment: +1 because i think yours is slightly more readable than @dtb's

Comment: Taking a couple of lines of code (which the OP already knew) and cramming it onto one line is not really the same thing as one expression.

Comment: I like it. Simple and elegant and takes the max so if your string is less than 0 you won't get an out of index exception.

Comment: +1 simple and to the point, covers all bases. The extension method proposed by Stecya is also good, but a bit over kill if you are only doing it once.

Comment: This is one line and a single expression--assuming the string is assigned to a variable. To slice a string returned by a function you would have to assign a variable.

Comment: Testing all answers and found this answer as the best implementation.

Comment: This approach fails on `null` input

Comment: You can also use the range indexer. Something like this here: var unknown = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()[^4..];

Answer (score 233):

You can use an [extension method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method#Current_C.23_solutions):

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string GetLast(this string source, int tail_length)
    {
       if(tail_length >= source.Length)
          return source;
       return source.Substring(source.Length - tail_length);
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
string mystring = "34234234d124";
string res = mystring.GetLast(4);
```

Comment: I like this, but I would probably just call it Last().  After all Substring() isn't GetSubstring().

Comment: Maybe call it Tail() as Last clashes with the Linq Extension Last().

Comment: +1 for making it "a lot longer than 1 line". It's so annoying to see unreadable code because of line savings.

Comment: Or call it Right() for consistency with VisualBasic as per @RJ Programmer's answer (I don't want to add another assembly just for one function).

Comment: An advantage of this extension method solution is you can slice a string returned by a function without having to assign a variable.

Comment: I love this solution.

Comment: Should the extension have a null check?  if(source != null && tail_length >= source.Length)

Answer (score 117):

**Update 2020**: C# 8.0 finally makes this easy:

```
> "C# 8.0 finally makes this easy"[^4..]
"easy"
```

You can also slice arrays in the same way, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-

This requires System.Range  unfortunately not available in .NET Framework https://apisof.net/catalog/3222de6d-b599-dd2f-07b1-8eb3d8120343

Comment: The best way =)

Comment: Sad it is only on .Net Core or/and Standard. This is beautiful.

Comment: This is another one of those times I wish I was still writing Python, where this has just been the normal way of doing things from the start.

Comment: Best solution for C# 8.0 and above

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're not sure the string will have at least 4 characters, then C# 8.0 ranges will still need the guard against ArgumentOutOfRangeException that Armen's answer gives. I can't think of anything more elegant than: `var s = "not quite so easy"; s[^Math.Min(19, s.Length)..];` :(

Comment: Here's an easier to read out of range protection.  Jam on a PadLeft or PadRight

`"C# 8.0 finally makes this easy".PadLeft(4)[^4..]`

Answer (score 69):

All you have to do is..

```
String result = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4);
```

Comment: Not if you want an exception to be thrown if the length is less than 4...

Comment: It throws `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.`

Answer (score 49):

Ok, so I see this is an old post, but why are we rewriting code that is already provided in the framework?

I would suggest that you add a reference to the framework DLL "Microsoft.VisualBasic"

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
//...

string value = Strings.Right("34234234d124", 4);
```

Comment: Nice example of a time to use the VB functionality

Comment: I love you. Most of my programming experience is VB, so finding out that I can use all of those functions that I'm so familiar with is awesome

Comment: I can never figure out if using MS.VB a good idea -- why is it shunted into the `VisualBasic` namespace? [`TextFieldParser`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5865879/1028230) is another example. Why are these utilities factored so strangely?

Comment: @ruffin: Essentially these were all VB6 built-in functions. They were implemented initially in the framework to make upgrading VB6 code easier. That said, there are many useful utility functions from VB6 that I like to use and being they are now part of the .NET framework, I can continue to leverage them in my C# code.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Am I right to assume that namespace is going to be wiped out at some point? And then, when you upgrade, you will have the problems that Microsoft tried to avoid when people were upgrading from VB6.

Comment: @Bomboca: We can be assured that it will continue as long a Microsoft continues to support Visual Basic. It is included in the 4.6 release and I cannot find anything either explicit or implied from MS that they plan to stop supporting VB.Net as a development language.

Comment: @RJProgrammer vb is still to common to be wiped out.

Comment: @Zack, why would you take on the dependency of an *entire* dll to save yourself a 3 line extension method that could be added anywhere?  That solution doesn't scale well.  If the questions was about vb.... maybe, but I can't see a reason c# devs should take that in.

Comment: @KyleMit, the dependency is a framework component. It's already in the Global Assembly Cache and deployed with the dotnet framework. If this were a nuget or external reference, I'd understand your concern. 
Still you bring up a valid point. Of course, an extension method would be a workable solution here. However, that is also code to test, maintain and support. There are trade offs both ways. This response was just pointing out an alternative solution.

Comment: @RJProgrammer, all fair points, and certainly not harmful to point out when a method/solution already exists.  And comments are also an okay place to hash out the viability of a solution.  I wonder if this solution still works cross platform inside of .NET Core?  Anything that has to get pulled in (nuget, etc.) is a pretty hard dependency, but even relying on a library assumes no breaking changes when it's reversioned.  But good point on testing, maintaining your own code as well as a trade off though

Comment: I always wondered - if there is real concern about VB, why not add these to the c# libs?  I'm c# now, but I used to love programming in VB.  Everything just worked, and I preferred just typing rather than constantly pecking out special characters - and don't get me started on case sensitivity in programming languages.

Answer (score 30):

```
string mystring = "34234234d124";
mystring = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length-4)
```

Answer (score 27):

Using [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) is actually quite short and readable:

```
 var result = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - Math.Min(4, mystring.Length));
 // result == "d124"
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is another alternative that shouldn't perform too badly (because of [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)):

`new string(mystring.Reverse().Take(4).Reverse().ToArray());`

Although an extension method for the purpose `mystring.Last(4)` is clearly the cleanest solution, albeit a bit more work.

Comment: @BrianWhite People are cranky after new year's?

Comment: Nice solution. i like it. But you forgot other Reverse to get correct string. Must be: new string(mystring.Reverse().Take(4).Reverse().ToArray());

Comment: Aah yes, you are correct - my mental compiler didn't think that far. Sadly that makes it appear even worse! :)

Comment: Because of ToArray there is no deferred execution

Comment: And there wouldn't be anyway because of `new string`

Comment: I don't think you understand, @BjörnAliGöransson, my point was that the `Reverse().Take(4).Reverse()` don't each enumerate the entire string, it only happens at the final `ToArray` call. If there weren't such a thing as deferred execution, it would translate to `Reverse().ToArray().Take(4).ToArray().Reverse().ToArray()`. This, of course, assumes those extensions are the deferred type - which I didn't check. The String constructors don't accept IEnumerable, so you have to enumerate it to an array at that point.

Comment: dotnetcore 2.1 has `TakeLast()` method

Comment: It works but performance wise... I would take this as the last options. In fact the worse solution of all

Comment: Not only is this inefficient, if you want LINQ, why not just `mystring.Skip(mystring.Length - 4)`

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use `Substring` method of C#. For ex.

```
string str = "1110000";
string lastFourDigits = str.Substring((str.Length - 4), 4);
```

It will return result 0000.

Comment: This has been answered like 28 times and you added it again? And why use the two-parameters-overload instead of the one that only receives `startIndex`?

Comment: Exactly the answer i needed.Thanks for sharing @Amit Kumawat.

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution would be:

```
string mystring = "34234234d124";
string last4 = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4, 4);
```

Answer (score 11):

Definition:

```
public static string GetLast(string source, int last)
{
     return last >= source.Length ? source : source.Substring(source.Length - last);
}
```

Usage:

```
GetLast("string of", 2);
```

Result:

**of**

Answer (score 11):

```
string var = "12345678";

var = var[^4..];

// var = "5678"
```

This is index operator that literally means "take last four chars from end (^4) until the end (..)"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

Compared to some previous answers, the main difference is that this piece of code takes into consideration when the input string is:

1. Null
2. Longer than or matching the requested length
3. Shorter than the requested length.

Here it is:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(str.Length - length, length);
    }

    public static string MyLast(this string str, int length)
    {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        else if (str.Length >= length)
            return str.Substring(str.Length - length, length);
        else
            return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Improvement: You don't need to use "else" if you are using "return"

Answer (score 7):

**Full overview over variants:** I would like to extend the existing answer mentioning using new ranges in C# 8 or higher:
Just slicing with `mystring[^4..]` (here example 3) seems very easy, but this has some pitfalls as you will see:

To make the code usable for **all** possible strings, even those shorter than 4, there is some form of condition needed! If you want to copy code, I suggest example 5 or 6.

```
string mystring ="C# 8.0 finally makes slicing possible";
```

1: Slicing taking the end part- by specifying **how many characters to omit from the beginning**- this is, what VS 2019 suggests:

```
string example1 = mystring[Math.Max(0, mystring.Length - 4)..] ;
```

2: Slicing taking the end part- by specifying **how many characters to take from the end**:

```
string example2 = mystring[^Math.Min(mystring.Length, 4)..] ;
```

3: Slicing taking the end part- **without using Max/Min but the ?: operator**:

```
string example3 = (mystring.length > 4)? mystring[^4..] : mystring);
```

Personally, I like the second and third variant more than the first.

[*MS doc reference for Indices and ranges:*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

**Null?** But we are not done yet concerning universality. Every example so far will throw an exception for null strings. To consider null (if you don´t use non-nullable strings with C# 8 or higher), and to do it without 'if' (classic example 'with if' already given in another answer) we need:

4: Slicing **considering null**- by specifying how many **characters to omit**:

```
string example4 = mystring?[Math.Max(0, mystring.Length - 4)..] ?? string.Empty;
```

5: Slicing **considering null**- by specifying how many **characters to take**:

```
string example5 = mystring?[^Math.Min(mystring.Length, 4)..] ?? string.Empty;
```

6: Slicing **considering null** with the ?: operator (and two other '?' operators ;-) :
(You cannot put that in a whole in a string interpolation e.g. for WriteLine.)

```
string example6 = (mystring?.Length > 4) ? filePath[^4..] : mystring ?? string.Empty;
```

7: Equivalent **variant** with good old Substring() **for C# 6 or 7.x:**
(You cannot put that in a whole in a string interpolation e.g. for WriteLine.)

```
string example7 = (mystring?.Length > 4) ? mystring.Substring(mystring.Length- 4) : mystring ?? string.Empty;
```

**Graceful degradation?**
I like the new features of C#. Putting them on one line like in the last examples maybe looks a bit excessive. We ended up a little perl´ish didn´t we?
But it´s a good example for learning and ok for me to use it once in a tested library method.
Even better that we can get rid of null in modern C# if we want and avoid all this null-specific handling.

Such a library/extension method as a shortcut is really useful. Despite the advances in C# you have to write your own to get something easier to use than repeating the code above for every small string manipulation need.

I am one of those who began with BASIC, and 40 years ago there was already Right$(,). Funny, that it is possible to use Strings.Right(,) from VB with C# still too as was shown in another answer.
This was and is very easy to use without having all the edge cases..

C# has chosen precision over graceful degradation (in opposite to old BASIC) by which I mean, it always throws an exception if something not clear happens instead of using a default which works for most cases..
Consequent, but I don't think that this way has much future as last examples show.
Having default configurations with options would be more convenient. Anyway it is easy to overcome this with some self-written library routines.

So copy any appropriate variant you like in these answers and define a graceful shortcut function for yourself, mine is an extension function called RightChars(int).

Answer (score 6):

```
mystring = mystring.Length > 4 ? mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4, 4) : mystring;
```

Comment: Nice, but I think that you meant `=` not `=+`.

Comment: mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4, 4)
is the same as:
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4)

Answer (score 5):

It is just this:

```
int count = 4;
string sub = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - count, count);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
            string x = "34234234d124";

            string y = x.Substring(x.Length - 4);
```

Comment: You could consider showing a working example with sample inputs and outputs. That said, this is a strait forward answer.

Answer (score 3):

This won't fail for any length string.

```
string mystring = "34234234d124";
string last4 = Regex.Match(mystring, "(?!.{5}).*").Value;
// last4 = "d124"
last4 = Regex.Match("d12", "(?!.{5}).*").Value;
// last4 = "d12"
```

This is probably overkill for the task at hand, but if there needs to be additional validation, it can possibly be added to the regular expression.

**Edit:**  I think this regex would be more efficient:

```
@".{4}\Z"
```

Comment: Definitely overkill. I would stick with simple string methods for this.

Comment: The second variant does not return a three letter string when called with a three letter argument, so it is not equivalent to your first ingenious version using negative lookahead! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-) is the easiest way for me. No many codes is required.

In your case, you can get what you want like this:

```
// the ^ operator indicates the element position from the end of a sequence
string str = "34234234d124"[^4..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic `Last<T>`. That will work with ANY `IEnumerable`, including string.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Last<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int nLastElements)
{
    int count = Math.Min(enumerable.Count(), nLastElements);
    for (int i = enumerable.Count() - count; i < enumerable.Count(); i++)
    {
        yield return enumerable.ElementAt(i);
    }
}
```

And a specific one for string:

```
public static string Right(this string str, int nLastElements)
{
    return new string(str.Last(nLastElements).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Overkill.  Maybe something like enumerable.Skip(enumerable.Count() - nLastElements) ?

Comment: I disagree with @BuhBuh about this being overkill.  But I prefer "Last" to "Right" as a name.  I am a bit squeamish about overloading the existing Last of IEnumerable<T>.  I'm kind of leaning towards "Skip," too.

Comment: I like this solution. Not simple but intresting when learning IEnumerable.

Comment: At the very least, cache `enumerable.Count()`

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using TakeLast method, for example: new String(text.TakeLast(4).ToArray())

Answer (score 0):

I threw together some code modified from various sources that will get the results you want, and do a lot more besides. I've allowed for negative int values, int values that exceed the length of the string, and for end index being less than the start index. In that last case, the method returns a reverse-order substring. There are plenty of comments, but let me know if anything is unclear or just crazy. I was playing around with this to see what all I might use it for.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns characters slices from string between two indexes.
    /// 
    /// If start or end are negative, their indexes will be calculated counting 
    /// back from the end of the source string. 
    /// If the end param is less than the start param, the Slice will return a 
    /// substring in reverse order.
    /// 
    /// <param name="source">String the extension method will operate upon.</param>
    /// <param name="startIndex">Starting index, may be negative.</param>
    /// <param name="endIndex">Ending index, may be negative).</param>
    /// </summary>
    public static string Slice(this string source, int startIndex, int endIndex = int.MaxValue)
    {
        // If startIndex or endIndex exceeds the length of the string they will be set 
        // to zero if negative, or source.Length if positive.
        if (source.ExceedsLength(startIndex)) startIndex = startIndex < 0 ? 0 : source.Length;
        if (source.ExceedsLength(endIndex)) endIndex = endIndex < 0 ? 0 : source.Length;

        // Negative values count back from the end of the source string.
        if (startIndex < 0) startIndex = source.Length + startIndex;
        if (endIndex < 0) endIndex = source.Length + endIndex;         

        // Calculate length of characters to slice from string.
        int length = Math.Abs(endIndex - startIndex);
        // If the endIndex is less than the startIndex, return a reversed substring.
        if (endIndex < startIndex) return source.Substring(endIndex, length).Reverse();

        return source.Substring(startIndex, length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reverses character order in a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns>string</returns>
    public static string Reverse(this string source)
    {
        char[] charArray = source.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies that the index is within the range of the string source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool ExceedsLength(this string source, int index)
    {
        return Math.Abs(index) > source.Length ? true : false;
    }
```

So if you have a string like "This is an extension method", here are some examples and results to expect.

```
var s = "This is an extension method";
// If you want to slice off end characters, just supply a negative startIndex value
// but no endIndex value (or an endIndex value >= to the source string length).
Console.WriteLine(s.Slice(-5));
// Returns "ethod".
Console.WriteLine(s.Slice(-5, 10));
// Results in a startIndex of 22 (counting 5 back from the end).
// Since that is greater than the endIndex of 10, the result is reversed.
// Returns "m noisnetxe"
Console.WriteLine(s.Slice(2, 15));
// Returns "is is an exte"
```

Hopefully this version is helpful to someone. It operates just like normal if you don't use any negative numbers, and provides defaults for out of range params.

Answer (score 0):

```
string var = "12345678";

if (var.Length >= 4)
{
    var = var.substring(var.Length - 4, 4)
}

// result = "5678"
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you wanted the strings in between a string which is located 10 characters from the last character and you need only 3 characters.

Let's say `StreamSelected = "rtsp://72.142.0.230:80/SMIL-CHAN-273/4CIF-273.stream"`

In the above, I need to extract the `"273"` that I will use in database query

```
        //find the length of the string            
        int streamLen=StreamSelected.Length;

        //now remove all characters except the last 10 characters
        string streamLessTen = StreamSelected.Remove(0,(streamLen - 10));   

        //extract the 3 characters using substring starting from index 0
        //show Result is a TextBox (txtStreamSubs) with 
        txtStreamSubs.Text = streamLessTen.Substring(0, 3);
```

Comment: This question explicitly asks for the last four characters in the string. You seem to be answering a different question related to extracting things from the middle of the string. Also `Substring` already lets you pass in a start point and length so not sure why you wouldn't use that rather than using `Remove` to remove the beginning first.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Last(this string source, int tailLength)
{
  return tailLength >= source.Length ? source : source[^tailLength..];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more than the OP question, but is an example of how to use the last 3 of a string for a specific purpose. In my case, I wanted to do a numerical sort (LINQ OrderBy) on a number field that is stored as a string (1 to 3 digit numbers.) So, to get the string numbers to sort like numeric numbers, I need to left-pad the string numbers with zeros and then take the last 3. The resulting OrderBy statement is:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => string.Concat("00",x.Id)[^3..])
```

The string.Concat() used in the OrderBy statement results in strings like "001", "002", "011", "021", "114" which sort the way they would if they were stored as numbers.