# Omitting the first digit from a given number

Tags: c#, regex

I am given a contact number by a customer.
The client that this number is given to requires the first number to be omitted from the result.
I have used Regex to do this, but I'm curious if there is a more optimal way to do this.

```
var mobileNumber = "07123123123";
var homeNumber = "01511231231";

var pattern = "(.{10})$";

var omittedMobile = Regex.Split(mobileNumber, pattern)[1];
var omittedHome = Regex.Split(homeNumber, pattern)[1];

var mobileNumber = "07123123123";
var homeNumber = "01511231231";
```

I receive: 07123123123 - I provide 7123123123

Comment: Not very clear what is your objective but a simple _mobileNumber.Substring(1)_ should be enough (and it will work even if you have only 10 or less digits in the string)

Comment: It might be worth to sanity-check your requirements: The *real* requirement (as opposed to "the requirement as imagined by your customer") is probably *not* to blindly remove the first digit, but to "start the number with the area code", e.g. `01234...` should become `1234...`, `+441234...` should become `1234...` and `1234` should throw an error.

Comment: The task here looks to be just "get last X chars from string". It has [already been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413572/how-do-i-get-the-last-four-characters-from-a-string-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

Using string function [Substring(int startIndex)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_),

```
var mobileNumber = "07123123123";
Console.WriteLine(mobileNumber.Substring(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not treat it as a simple string and remove the first character?

```
mobileNumber.Substring(1);

//or

mobileNumber.Remove(0, 1);
```